# Resizing windows on Leopard = painful = Any better way then using the drag corner?

Tags: osx-leopard

Too many usability problems:

The mouse cursor does not change while over the drag area. You click and drag to find out that now your window is gone and you are dragging over the window underneath it.

Is there anyways to fix this? At least change the cursor over the drag area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used an app called Zoom that's very helpful with window resizing/dragging.

Comment: Not what I wanted but a nice suggestion. I am using it. Thanks!